# Does Azure Cloud Queue Incoming SMS Text Messages?

Tags: azure

Does Azure Communication queue incoming SMS text messages? How many? For how long?

Maybe a better question is: Does Event Grid have message queing? Because i believe SMS sends events to the Event Grid.

> Azure Communication Services SMS capabilities provide developers
> options to consume SMS received events. The events are posted to Azure
> Event Grid which provides out of the box integrations to process those
> using webhooks, Azure Functions, Power Automate / Logic App
> connectors, and more.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/receive-sms?pivots=programming-language-javascript

It's recommended to subscribe to events with a Storage Queue. That suggests that events are not queued automatically, and you must roll your own.

> if you’ve configured a dead letter for the subscription, it’ll be
> dropped over there (in a Storage container). Getting these dead letter
> events out of the Storage Account is a burden. Storage Queues are very
> cheap and have a very high uptime. When the Azure Function runtime isn’t running correctly for
> some reason, events aren’t lost but stored on the queue.
> https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/subscribe-to-queues-when-working-with-event-grid